# mysql import getting larger than original db

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

The size of the db files on the original host are 1.4Tb.  I'm moving this database to a gcloud hosted db, the import has been running almost a week now.  The new db is using up >1.5Tb.  Any thoughts on this, I'm scared it's running amuck.Thx, jake

Comment: I've seen this happen at work when the OSs are different versions (for us, it was Ubuntu). Also, verify that all character set and encoding settings (i.e., latin1 vs utf8) are identical between the source and destination. Differences there could cause this, too.

Comment: The gcloud storage measurement might include binary logs as well as data files. You could contact gcloud documentation or support to find out.

Comment: I recommend you try out gcloud with a smaller database until you get some experience with it.